# Access Forbidden while accessing log in airflow with CeleryExecutor

Tags: kubernetes, celery, airflow, azure-aks, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to deploy Airflow on kubernetes (on Azure Kubernetes Service) with the celery Executor. However, once a task is done, I get the following error while trying to access its logs:

```
*** Log file does not exist: /opt/airflow/logs/maintenance/clean_events/2021-08-23T14:46:18.953030+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://airflow-worker-0.airflow-worker.airflow.svc.cluster.local:8793/log/maintenance/clean_events/2021-08-23T14:46:18.953030+00:00/1.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. 403 Client Error: FORBIDDEN for url: http://airflow-worker-0.airflow-worker.airflow.svc.cluster.local:8793/log/maintenance/clean_events/2021-08-23T14:46:18.953030+00:00/1.log
For more information check: https://httpstatuses.com/403
```

my charts.yaml is pretty simple

```yaml
---
airflow:
   image:
      repository: myrepo.azurecr.io/maintenance-scripts
      tag: latest
      pullPolicy: Always
      pullSecret: "secret"
   executor: CeleryExecutor
   config:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "True"
      AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DELETE_WORKER_PODS: "False"
   users:
    - username: admin
      password: password
      role: Admin
      email: admin@example.com
      firstName: admin
      lastName: admin
rbac:
   create: true
serviceAccount:
    create: true
#postgresql:
#    enabled: true
workers:
    enabled: true
redis:
    enabled: true
flower:
    enabled: false
global:
  postgresql: {
      storageClass: managed
  }
persistence:
  fixPermissions: true
  storageClassName: managed
```

I have not been able to fix this, and it seems to be the most basic conf you can use on airflow, anyone knows where this could come from ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the same webserver secret configured for both webserver and workers: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#secret-key

It's been recently fixed as potential security vulnerability - now you need to know the secret key to be able to retrieve logs (it was unauthenticated before).

Comment: So thanks a lot, you just solved a bug I've been having for a few days ! Could you point me to where I should have found this info ?

Comment: It was a bit implicit (I mean you should set this variable to the same value everywhere anyway), but indeed it was not obvious, in the latest version (2.1.3) it is printed verbosely when you see this kind of error: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17410/files